# Can the word Gentoo be used in a derogatory way?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, pejorative-language

I was reading a Wikipedia article on [Gentoo Penguin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Penguin) and came across the following Paragraph.

> The application of Gentoo to the penguin is unclear. The Oxford
>   English Dictionary notes that Gentoo used to be an Anglo-Indian term
>   used as early as 1638 to distinguish Hindus in India from Muslims. The
>   English term originated from the Portuguese gentio (compare
>   "gentile"); in the 20th century the term came to be regarded as
>   derogatory.

I am particularly interested to know why the Portuguese word  gentio from which the English Term Gentoo originated is regarded as derogatory. In the similar context does the same English Term would also be regarded as derogatory similar to the root word?

**Context**
We have named our baby "Gentoo" and now I have realized that the term may be pejorative.

Comment: Here is an article on JSTOR that you may find interesting.  http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4410294?uid=3739976&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21101810018473

Also, I'm not sure how far you followed through, but here is another Wikipedia article that fits the bill a little more closely than the Penguin.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_(slang)

At a glance, I wouldn't be particularly concerned with it being perceived as derogatory.

Comment: Someone with access to the OED will probably soon confirm if the Wikipedia article is accurate or not. In the meantime, [according to this site](http://trivia.serendip.in/trivia/gentoo), the penguin was named _Gentoo_ because it is "characterised by a wide white stripe resembling a cap on the top of its head" which was "reminiscent of the headgear worn by the Gentoos of India".

Comment: [Hobson-Jobson](http://archive.org/stream/hobsonjobsonbein00yuleuoft#page/366/mode/2up) (1903) has a long article on the word which gives no evidence of derogatory use (and remarks, moreover, that the word has at the time of publication become obsolete among English speakers). But the most innocent ethnic, national, racial or other corporate designation will become derogatory if the people whom it designates are regarded with contempt by the people who use the term.

Comment: Some quick points in no particular order. 1) Portuguese is off-topic here. However, luckily 2) the connotations of a Portuguese word a hundred years ago have no relevance whatsoever to the connotations of an English word today; see [etymological fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy). 3) You've already named your baby, so it's too late. 4) Any, absolutely any word can be used in a derogatory way. You can name your child Love, and I guarantee you it will get picked on and come home crying and end up cursing you forever.

Comment: @Reg, yes, I agree with you both on 5) and 6) points, however there are some words that we can more simply  use in derogatory way and others, like "love", that we, yes, can use that way, but only if we are like the demons.

Comment: Note that it is not the Portuguese but the **English** term which Wikipedia says "came to be regarded as derogatory".

Comment: @Carlo: It's not too uncommon for schoolchildren to behave like demons – in regards to teasing classmates, at least. ;^) I agree with Reg, though, I hadn't heard of this word before I read this question, so I can't see myself considering it derogatory. Moreover, I've known quite a few Richards who went by _Dick_, and one of the most common names for boys in the U.S. is _John_, which can also be used as slang for a toilet, or for a prostitute's customer. Then there's Jerry (jerry-built), Bill (water bill), Warren (rabbit warren), Rob (a bank), etc. To be frank, you've got nothing to fret about.

Comment: @J.R. yes, I agree with you. When we open our minds the possibilities become endless: John, Bill, Jeff, Love, and so on. It all becomes relative. One’s view becomes a relative perspective from which to see the derogatory words. But, this way, they melt away because it doesn’t matter anymore :)

Comment: At least ***"Gentoo"*** doesn't have a derogatory word that rhymes with it which is amother favorite pastime of school children.  ***"Gentoo"*** is unique and beautiful. Pity the Barts, Chucks, Reginas, Garys, Ricks and Pattys of the school yard! :-)

Comment: @Kristina: Every name, including Gentoo, has a derogatory word that rhymes with it.

Comment: @Hugo - I'll take your word for it - I couldn't think of one. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I came through didn't found ***portuguese Gentio*** from which the English Term Gentoo originated to be derogatory but the parent word **gentilis** from late Latin has some [concerns](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gentilis).

Here is a brief etymology of the word *Gentoo*.

> [Gentoo [archaic] | Gentoos [plural]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gentoo)
>   First use: 1638
>   Origin: Portuguese gentio, literally, gentile, from Late Latin gentilis
>
> [Gentoo [archaic]](http://www.yourdictionary.com/gentoo)
>   Origin: Portuguese gentio, heathen, gentile from Latin gentilis: see "gentile"
>
> [Gentoo [sometimes not capital, archaic] | Gentoos [plural]](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gentoo)
>   First use: 17th century
>   Origin: from Portuguese gentio pagan (literally: Gentile)
>
> [gentoo | gentoo penguin](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gentoo)
>   First use: mid 19th century
>   Origin: perhaps from Anglo-Indian Gentoo "a Hindu", from Portuguese gentio "gentile"
>
> [gentoo | gentoos [plural]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gentoo)
>   Origin: Of Anglo-Indian origin (17th century), apparently a corrupted form of gentile ("pagan").

Also, do consider this [link](http://www.finedictionary.com/Gentoo.html) for usage examples in various media and articles.

*Abhijeet as your name suggests, you are from India thereof a personal answer is that though in English and other foreign languages the Gentoo may have different meanings but as far as Indian meaning goes, the word is often used in a combination: jeev-jantu which offcourse would be something which can be teased by naughty fellow mates.*

Comment: -1 _gentio_ != _genito_

Comment: @coleopterist Thanks, don't know how i missed something this big.